# Hide class name from Allure report

Tags: java, allure

I am trying to tune an allure report so that it looks perfect for my needs. I already came far, but there are still the names of the classes in the report and I want to hide them.

What I did so far is: I use different testNG.xml's for the different user journeys and use the tests in there for our different devices.

When I have a look at the Suites tab in allure, it looks like this:

JOURNEY1 ( name)
-- DEVICE 1 ( name)
-- -- *ClassName* (this is what I want to hide)
-- -- -- Test 1 (description of the @Test's)
...

What I want it to look like is this:

JOURNEY1 ( name)
-- DEVICE 1 ( name)
-- -- Test 1 (description of the @Test's)
...

Is this even possible? How can I do this?

Thank you very much in advance!